# R - function, matrix, apply

Tags: r, matrix, apply, cbind

Write your own function that returns the 75th percentile of a vector. Apply this 
function to all columns of matrix b.

Here's matrix b:

```
b = matrix(runif(1000*18, min=1000, max=10000), 1000, 18)
```

And here's the function I've created using indexing.

```
percentileOfAVector <- function(vector,percentile){
    adjustedVector=vector[0:floor(percentile * length(vector))]
    return (adjustedVector)
}
```

I was wondering if I can use the apply function to adjust the b vector that I've got. Or should I use a for loop?

PS: I tried to do it with a for loop but I had some problems with cbind when I was trying to store the results of my function in a matrix.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think your question needs to be a little more specific. Can you use the apply function to adjust the b vector? Yes!

Comment: You may wish to rephrase the first sentence so it doesn't sound like homework

Comment: A bit of semantics that you seem to have missed. A percentile is a single number (and in statistical parlance it's an "order statistic"). Returning a shortened vector is not going to get you any points in your HW.

Comment: @BondedDust I searched for a function that does that. The quantile function. From your understanding of your question, that's what I am asked? If so why would should I write my own function?(learning how to write a simple function is one answer).

Comment: @SeñorO Yes I was wondering how can I use the apply function that way. What's the proper way to write my function so I can use it with apply?

Comment: I suspect your teachers want you to learn how to deal with the 'order' function and demonstrate how you would use it in writing a function. (I also suspect people here will expect more effort to be demonstrated on your part. The multiple questions seems to be your effort at avoid reading your textbooks and looking at the examples in the help files.)

Comment: @BondedDust I don't think sorting is their purpose. Maybe you're right about the percentile thing and using the quantile function will do the trick.

Comment: @BondedDust Just go what you meant after some digging about what percentile really is. I will post my answer shortly. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: In `apply`'s "FUN" argument, you can either build an anonymous function or use the name of the function and, also, pass extra arguments needed. I guess, here, you might want something like (i) anonymous: `apply(b, 2, function(x) percentileOfAVector(x, 0.75))` or (ii) `apply(b, 2, percentileOfAVector, 0.75)`. From the question, though, I get that something like `apply(b, 2, quantile, 0.75)` or `apply(b, 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.75))` could be helpful. You can, also, see the code of `quantile` function to get some ideas: `page(stats:::quantile.default)`.

Comment: @alexis_laz Thank you very much. That was some really helpful information. You helped me understand how apply function works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the percentile of a vector (single value):

```
apply(b, 2, function (x) quantile(x, prob=0.75))
```

But it seems this isn't what you mean with percentile. If what you want is to return a vector with the observations that fall within the 75th percentile:

```
percentOfVector <- function(vector, percentile) {
    perc <- quantile(vector, prob=percentile)
    vector[which(vector <= perc)]
}

apply(b, 2, function (x) percentOfVector(x, 0.75))
```